# Reading data from text file using AJAX doesn't work as expected

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am writing a simple online message board where people can post messages. I hope people can see new messages without refreshing the page so I'm using jquery to do $.ajax() on a text file containing messages. What's very weird is, sometimes the ajax doesn't work. Even though the message.txt has been updated, the data read from it in ajax is still old.

I observed that after I make a modification of my code on the server, it would stop working correctly. And clearing all browser history also makes it stop working correctly for a while. I have no idea what's causing the problem.

This is the code in my php file

```
#!/usr/local/bin/php
<?php
ob_start();
session_name('message_board');
session_start();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) or !$_SESSION['loggedin']) {
    header('Location: index.php');
}
else {
?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['message'])) {
    $file = fopen('message.txt', 'a') or die('Can not open file');
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
    $date_time = new DateTime();
    fwrite($file, $_POST['message'].'@~,'.$_SESSION['username'].'@~,'.$date_time->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'@~;');
    fclose($file);
}
?>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Message Board</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="msg_board.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="msg_board.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1 id="msg_board_title">
        Awesome Message board
    </h1>
    <form action="logout.php">
        <p id="welcome_message">
            Welcome to the Message Board! Your email address is <?php echo $_SESSION['username'] ?>
            <input type="submit" value="log out">
        </p>
    </form>
    <section id="all_messages">
    </section>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
        <fieldset>
            <p>
                <textarea rows="8" name="message" id="posting_area" required></textarea>
            </p>
        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
<?php } ?>

</html>
```

This is the javascript

```
$.ajax({
    url: "message.txt",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
        let large_text = "";
        if (data !== "") {
            let msg_blocks = data.split("@~;");
            for (let i = 0; i < msg_blocks.length - 1; ++i) {
                temp = "<p>";
                temp += msg_blocks[i].split("@~,")[0];
                temp += "<br>";
                temp += msg_blocks[i].split("@~,")[1];
                temp += "<br>";
                temp += msg_blocks[i].split("@~,")[2];
                temp += "</p>";
                large_text = temp + large_text;
            }
        }
        else {
            large_text = "<p>Post something! There hasn't been any messages yet!</p>";
        }
        $("#all_messages").html(large_text);
    }
});
```

A sample from message.txt

```
Hi@~,hello@test.com@~,2019-06-04 17:58:35@~;
```

Not only would it stop working right after I clear browser history or change any file related to these on my server, it also doesn't fulfill the one reason I use AJAX. I'm hoping it would show new messages other users post on their computers without me having to refresh, but that doesn't happen either. I think my usage of php POST and javascript AJAX are very standard. I've spent an entire afternoon already and feeling nauseous literally. Please help!

Just to clarify: By AJAX not working properly, I mean it doesn't update the change to the webpage, even though I've checked the text file indeed has been updated by php. No errors reported anywhere.

Comment: What do you mean by "sometimes the ajax doesn't work" Is it returning an error? or is it always returning the same data? If it's always returning the same data it could be because the messages.txt is being cached.

Comment: @Jeemusu I mean the ajax in javascript doesn't update the <section id="all_messages">. I checked my text file on my server immediately after I post a new message. It is indeed immediately saved with the new message. But there's no change in <section id="all_messages">. Also, if some other user post new message, they would also change the message.txt. But the javascript function doesn't  reflect that change in <section id="all_messages"> either.

Comment: @Jeemusu Weird thing is, after I clear browser history or change the code or message.txt on the server, any new post wouldn't be reflected either. Although I have checked that php successfully records all new messages into message.txt, javascript just doesn't reflect the update in <section id="all_messages">. However, after some time, 1 or 2 minutes I suppose, javascript would start working properly, immediately showing new messages in <section id="all_messages"> after I submit a new message. But this still only happens on one computer. Changes made by others wouldn't be reflected still.

Comment: @Jeemusu OMG you're right! It's because of the Cache! I'm gonna do some further testing, but i think this is the fix!

Comment: If you want an easy way to force the text file to not be cached, you can append an always changing querystring, by changing `url: "message.txt"` to `url: "message.txt?cacheBust=" + (new Date).getTime()`.